# WPF Tree view complicated hierarchy

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview, datatemplate

In my code behind, I have an Observable Collection of say ObservableCollection.
I am trying to create a data template so as to view this data in a treeview exactly as it is defined in the model.

```
public class MainItem
{
    public string MainItemName { get; set; }
    public List<CategoryDetail> GoodCategories { get; set; }
    public List<CategoryDetail> BadCategories { get; set; }
    public List<SubItem> AllSubItems{ get; set; }
}

public class CategoryDetail
{
    public string CatId { get; set; }
    public string  CatName { get; set; }
    public List<SubItem> CatSubItems { get; set; }
    public List<CategoryDetail> CatSubCategories { get; set; }
}

public class SubItem
{
    public int SubItemId { get; set; }
    public string SubItemName { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

I have got only partial success as shown above.The progress I have made till now

```
<TreeView  Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding CatSubCategories}">

                <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding MainItemName}" />
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding CatSubItems}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource IdAndNameInAGridTemplate}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CatName}" />
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: MainItem should only have a collection of Categories.  A Category has a collection of Items.  Seems obvious from your expected tree layout.  Not sure why you're having a problem.  Simple relationship to map out and design.

Comment: One main data object has 3 different collection of another data objects (that too can be nested). I am looking for some guidance in that perspective.